# Is it monotonically non-increasing or non-decreasing

Tags: functions

In the graph below

[image]

I could not understand whether at the point x=1 the function is monotonically non-increasing or monotonically non-decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, you must know the definition of what it means for a function $f$ to be nondecreasing or nonincreasing. The former requires that $x > y$ implies $f(x) \geq f(y)$; the latter requires that $x > y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Intuitively, imagine you are moving a point along the horiozontal axis in the positive direction. If the graph of $f$ does not go down, then it is nondecreasing (cf. the formal requirement above).

Now you see that the function under consideration is nondecreasing on the given region of interest.

Answer (score 1):

This function is monotonically increasing. Because according to definition of monotonically increasing function it can be constant for a particular period. But this function is not a strictly increasing function on $x\in [0,2]$. But it is strictly increasing in [0,1].

Comment: @koolman, do this answer looks cool to you? If yes then accept.

Comment: I believe that this function is monotonically non-decreasing (and not monotonically increasing) because at 1 ≤ x ≤ 2, y does not increase.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is monotonically increasing on $[0,2]$.

Hence the function is monotonically non decreasing on $[0,2]$.